# Kendo Autocomplete datasource shows No data found

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I am implementing Address Autocomplete in a textbox by calling the third party API through jquery ajax call using kendoAutoComplete.
When I type in the textbox, it is making an ajax call to the API and returning the data in console.Log().
But the suggestion in the textbox says - "No data found".

For example:

```
<script>
  var data = ["One", "Two"];
  $("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: data
  });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://dojo.telerik.com/IzuxETAr/2

Comment: @rrk Yes. I checked the Console.Log(), and it is returning all the data. But the in the UI, it is showing "No data found"

Comment: Could you please share your full code along with backend controller , model and HTML bindings as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is set the serverFiltering ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/serverfiltering)) of the dataSource to `true`. Take a look at this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#products").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataTextField: "ProductName",
        filter: "contains",
        minLength: 2,
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/IqAjomaJ